# Crash on iOS 15 devices with the app build with XCode15.2, dyld: Symbol not found: _$s10Foundation13URLComponentsV3urlAA3URLVSgvg

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcframework

My app has a pod dependency (xcframework), `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` was changed to YES when generating the xcframework.

After adding the pod dependency in the Podfile the app crash:

```
dyld[21474]: Symbol not found: _$s10Foundation13URLComponentsV3urlAA3URLVSgvg
  Referenced from: /Users/user_repo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../data/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../MyApp.app/Frameworks/PodDependency.framework/PodDependency
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 15.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

The app is build on XCode15.2 and don't crash on iOS16+.
Cocoapods version: 1.15.2

I already tried to set `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` to YES for the specific pod in the Podfile of my project.

Comment: Do you find solution?